# [python]I want an image to be sent as a retweet on twitter via tweepy, when the bot is tagged

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want an image to be sent as a retweet on Twitter via Tweepy, when the bot is tagged, but I've hit a wall and can not figure out why. It is detecting the image in the external file, but not using it. I know it's a bit vague, but the documentation on Tweepy is a pain for me to understand, as I just picked up Tweepy yesterday. Any help is appreciated!!!

```py
import tweepy
import time
import os



#keys

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

#auth

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)



media = api.media_upload('cat_image.jpg')


#aquiring mentions
mentions = api.mentions_timeline()

#file import

FILE_NAME = 'last_seen_id.txt'

#operations

def retrieve_last_seen_id(file_name):
    f_read = open(file_name, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(f_read.read().strip())
    f_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, file_name):
    f_write = open(file_name, 'w')
    f_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    f_write.close()
    return

def reply_to_tweets():
    print('replying to tweets...')
    #id fetching
    last_seen_id = retrieve_last_seen_id(FILE_NAME)
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(
        last_seen_id,
        tweet_mode='extended')
    for mention in reversed(mentions):
        print(str(mention.id) + ' - ' + mention.full_text)
        last_seen_id = mention.id
        store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, FILE_NAME)
        if 'cat' in mention.full_text.lower():
            print('found user @!')
            print('responding....')
            un = '@' + mention.user.screen_name
            #response tweet
            tweet = 'un'
            api.update_status(un, media, mention.id)





while True:
    reply_to_tweets()
    time.sleep(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what the exact error you're seeing is, but I think you're saying that the image file is read, and the Tweet is sent, but the media is not attached?

`api.media_upload()` returns a `Media` object, which will have its own values. You need to pass the `media.media_id` value as the parameter to `update_status()`

```
api.update_status(un, media.media_id, mention.id)
```

If the media uploaded successfully in the earlier step, that should work.